# Do you use a PHP IDE?

Tags: php-ide

I've programmed for six years, and in that time, I've never used a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). I feel perfectly fine using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), the [Linux shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) command line and [Subversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) command line for my web application development. When I'm asked to work on other people's projects, or open source projects, I can generally find my way around after a quick system architecture overview.

Recently, I was curious about PHP IDEs. I downloaded [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans), but I lost patience debugging installation problems.

It makes me wonder, will my productivity increase substantially with the use of a good PHP IDE?  What percentage of [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)/PHP developers use a PHP IDE?

Comment: Your productivity probably will increase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I **always** use an IDE now, **if** it supports refactoring.  I may use it in addition to, or alongside, Vim or Emacs, but refactoring is now an integral part of my development style and having automated refactoring tools is essential.

If you're only going to use the editor features of whatever IDE you choose, you probably won't benefit much.  The benefit is when:

- the IDE can do for us something that would take us much longer, OR
- the IDE provides information that we would otherwise need to work to find

Answer (score 7):

I have used NetBeans in the past for PHP projects and liked it a lot. The fact I liked it is just my opinion, but I don't remember having any install issues. NetBeans synced up great with my teams [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion) server and things worked smoothly.

Comment: heh, you got me.  I got lazy and gave up once i realized i didn't have a few dependencies or jre installed.  I'll try harder!

Comment: Netbeans is built on dependancies. But don't worry, they're free. ;)

Answer (score 6):

I use Eclipse.  It's bloated, unwieldy, slow and quirky, but I find that it has some features that make me a better/faster developer.  The two main things I like about developing PHP with Eclipse are:

- Function documentation tooltips.  Given that PHP lacks a standard parameter order for a lot of things, this is especially useful with the `str` family of functions.  I don't have to remember whether a particular function order is `($haystack,$needle)` or `($needle,$haystack)`, I can just type the name of the function and hover over it.
- "Jump into" functionality.  Highlight a function and hit 'F3', and it will take you to the class or file where that function is defined.  This is ***extremely*** helpful.

There's other features that are useful as well, although not as profound.  Things like autocomplete and PHPDoc comment templates (type `/**` and it creates a basic block comment pre-filled with your parameters) tend to be handy.

Due to deficiencies with Eclipse, I tend to develop with multiple tools.  For example, I find UltraEdit's "Find in multiple files" functionality to be excellent (as well as "edit in Column mode" for batch SQL edits), and I usually have it running alongside Eclipse.

I've tried NetBeans several times, but each time I've installed it in the past, the internal PHP function documentation has been broken, so hovering over any built-in PHP function results in an intellisense box saying "PHPDoc Not Found".  I found that extremely aggravating, and each time have gone back to Eclipse.  I like the looks of it, but I need that functionality (a vague reference to it on some forum has one of the developers saying that the build script is broken so it's not linking the docs properly, but they had yet to fix it as of my last attempt).

Answer (score 4):

I use NetBeans too. So far the best from what I've tried. Zend Studio is terrible and Eclipse is beyond any criticism (you cannot just double click php file to open it in Eclipse, for starters). There are several more free and commercial IDEs but most of them for Windows only.

Edit: tools I use most often are: method suggestion, refactoring, "go to declaration/defintion", "find usage", debuging (obviously, since it underlines erroneous statements).

Comment: "you cannot just double click php file to open it in Eclipse, for starters"


To clarify - you must mean from outside the editor (ie. Explorer/Finder/etc.). I dont see this as a big issue-In fact i cant see a use case for this myself. I cant imagine having a file type associated with Eclipse or any IDE that just sounds frustrating. On the other hand something i do find important - ie. being able to arbitrarily add/remove/edit file extensions isnt possible from within NetBeans That might make sense for compiled languages but not for scripting languages.

Comment: I meant exactly that and it is a big issue for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I use Eclipse with a PHP plugin and have been pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Aptana Studio (Eclipse) for a few years and it had a decent PHP editor with code hinting built-in. However, the new version of Aptana Studio now uses PHP Development Tools (PDT) instead of Aptana's own editor. I never had good luck with PDT, but hopefully development will improve now that Aptana is involved in the project.

Comment: Negatives: it's a bit slow.
Positives: It's **packed** with productivity features.
Conclusion: with some RAM, Aptana is awesome.

Comment: @namespaceform: Truth - Eclipse is definitely a beast in terms of system resources.

Answer (score 2):

I use NetBeans (on Windows and Linux), and  I have used [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) in the past (on Windows and Linux) and [phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php) (on Windows) which is a commercial tool.

All three have approximately the same feature set, and all three can be used to debug PHP code.

[ATM](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ATM#Adverb), I prefer NetBeans.

Previously I used plain editors such as [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++) and [TextPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextPad), my efficiency coding increased using an IDE with code-completion and runtime debugging.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a PHP person, but from my (probably similar) Perl perspective, I find that the following functions of IDE are useful/not (as far as what I perceive to be IDE functions at least)

- Code styling (syntax hihgliting) and block folding - Highly useful. But this is a feature of a high-end editor rather than IDE proper, to be honest (e.g. it is included in non-IDE editor UltraEdit, not only in IDE-proper superset of UltraEdit Studio). Ditto for other features that i'd consider programming editor rather than IDE - e.g. FTP/source code repository integration, block selection, regex support, etc...
- Code analysis - function lists, etc... Useful but not life-shattering. A good intelligent hints would be nice but again not "must have".
- Integration with tools: For Perl, since there's no building, projects, compilation etc... as separate complicated steps, I found the need for IDE (and thus the win from using one) to be negligible. Other people might disagree.
- Integrated debugging - I never heard of a good IDE with integrated Perl debugging (my ideal for such functionality would always lie with Borland's Turbo series of IDEs :) ). But I would probably find it very useful/helpful given the crappy Perl debugging GUI people use, if I ever found one.

Answer (score 2):

IDEs speed up development so much, just autocomplete is so useful.

I use [CodeLobster](http://www.codelobster.com/) which is really great and free, but it is especially good if you can afford to shell out money (and acutally have use for) for their various extensions for popular open source applications like [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've used almost every editor I can think of for Windows and Linux, and I'd have to say that if I use an IDE these days - I love [Eclipse PHP Developer Tools](http://eclipse.org/pdt)  (PDT). For beginners, I'd recomment the all-in-one.

Eclipse is such a good development platform, and everyone seems to like making plugins for it (as it's completely cross-OS, too).  Google has made their [Google Web Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit) (GWT) and Android plugins for Eclipse over other IDEs. [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Flex#Versions), [Zend Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Studio), and [Aptana Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptana#Aptana_Studio) are just glorified versions of Eclipse as well.

Additionally, there are cool tools like [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) and Outline view (shows all functions in PHP / JavaScript, classes and rules in [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)), File Search [/ and Replace] with regular expression support, and easy comparison to local or remote files. These tend to speed up my overall development time, as I think they would for you too.

NOTE: There's a bit of a learning curve with Eclipse, and it's harder to simply edit a file at a time (it's best if you make projects), so it's really a matter of preference. If you're a professional PHP developer and you spend a majority of time on larger projects, I'd really recommend at least trying it out.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29). I find it the easiest and cleanest.

Comment: And least productive. You don't get autocompletion, which you definitely need for a language as messed up as PHP. You can't jump directly to a function. The list goes on.

Comment: I find it to be fairly productive.  Autocompletion isn't a huge deal for me, same thing for jumping directly to a function.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) + [PDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_Development_Tools) and NetBeans. I much prefer Eclipse.

I think any productivity gains are going to vary depending on both the developer and the nature of the project. I use [TextMate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextMate) or [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) for small projects, while I reserve IDEs for larger/more complex projects or ones with underlying APIs I am not familiar with. Having a built-in API completion is a big help when a project or its underlying framework have so many methods you can't possibly learn and remember all their signatures and return types (at least for the duration of the iteration one is working on). Also debugger integration on complex projects can be a huge timesaver (especially if you're not using a testing suite).

Another thing to keep in mind is that to see a big gain in efficiency, you have to learn how to use the toolset of the IDE efficiently which will have a learning curve. In my experience that cure hasn't been major in either IDE I've used, but it is there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use an IDE but I also work on fairly small projects in PHP.  I use textmate which is a bit like a *nix editor on mac with nice shell integration.  For scripting languages in general I don't use IDEs.  Personally, the only time I really appreciate an IDE is when you must compile/link.  I've never been a fan of make etc.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse PDT seems to work for me.  I'm not a web developer, but took on revamping a website for a non-profit who had their web developer leave due to job relocation.  Without any documentation or system overview, I was able to find my way around and make changes simply using Eclipse's variable information pop-up box tool (I'm not sure what it is formally called, but I hope you get the picture).  From a productivity point of view, the auto-indent and variable/keyword auto-completion features is a great speed booster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, I recommend [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/). It has a great feature set - integrated [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol), [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion), [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) editor, terminal, etc. and a slick interface. It's US$99, but it is well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [Komodo Edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveState_Komodo) by ActiveState. I use the lite version of the software, and it keeps project files together, has code complete, code hightlighting, the works.